# Deleting row in xml file

Tags: c#, xml

Hey guys imagine i get a variable with a xml structure like this:

```
<Maintest>
   <test text="qwe" value="123"></test>
   <test text="qwer" value="1234"></test>
   <teste text="qwert" value="12345"></teste>
</Maintest>
```

I already can add a row on it but if the user wants to **DELETE** the item test "qwer" with value="1234" how can i do it ?
Thanks guy for reading my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `System.Xml.Linq` namespace, you can create and instance XDocument:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"
    <Maintest>
        <test text=""qwe"" value=""123""></test>
        <test text=""qwer"" value=""1234""></test>
        <teste text=""qwert"" value=""12345""></teste>
    </Maintest>"
);
```

Then you can use nice set of `System.Xml.Linq` extension methods that work on collections:

```
doc.Descendants("test").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("text") == "qwer").Remove();
```

Or you can use magic one-liner using [XPath-based query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (need to include `System.Xml.XPath` namespace):

```
doc.XPathSelectElements("//test[@text='qwer']").Remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can used below mentioned code:

```
    xdoc.Elements("Maintest").Elements("test").Where(
                    elemet => elemet.Attribute("text").Value == "qwert")
.ToList().ForEach(i => i.Remove());
```

Comment: This is not going to work. "test" are not root elements and there is a potential exception if "text" attribute is not present.